# pictures of the layout.phtml are not displayed

Tags: image, zend-framework, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [images in Zend Framework layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414289/images-in-zend-framework-layout)

The problem that I'm having is that the images of the **layout.phtml** are not displayed in the action views

When I put in this url `http://localhost/application/public/controller` the images are displayed correctly but when the url is (for example) `http://localhost/application/public/controller/any-action(even the index action)` pictures of the **layout.phtml** are not displayed.

All my images are located in a directory in the `public` directory of the application.

I don't know the source of that problem or how to fix it so please help me

Comment: You should probably set up a vhost for the application. What kind of server are you running locally?

Answer (score 3):

you should use URL helper for dealing with paths

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/logo.png'); ?>" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i added <?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/
to all the images of my layout and it works now

Comment: you may then mark it as accepted answer..

Comment: If the answer worked you can mark it as accepted, so it will be helpful to newbies to zend framework :)